# Extracting specific values from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I have a JSON object in Python from the result of a call to an API (using urllib2) generated as follow:

```
results = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
json1 = json.loads(results)
```

This generates a JSON object that contains something similar the following (truncated due to size):

```
"http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/895ba8ff-4c32-3ae1-9615-9a9a9a1bcb39/cat/1":{
    "_typeGroup":"topics",
    "category":"http://d.opencalais.com/cat/Calais/Entertainment_Culture",
    "classifierName":"Calais",
    "categoryName":"Entertainment_Culture",
    "score":1
},
"http://d.opencalais.com/genericHasher-1/b6a2d07d-133b-35ad-85e2-54d524e750cf":{
    "_typeGroup":"entities",
    "_type":"TVShow",
    "name":"Hard Knocks",
    "_typeReference":"http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/em/e/TVShow",
    "instances":[
          {
          "detection":"[ New York Jets during the summer of 2010 on HBO's ]Hard Knocks[.\n]",
          "prefix":" New York Jets during the summer of 2010 on HBO's ",
          "exact":"Hard Knocks",
          "suffix":".\n",
          "offset":135,
          "length":11
          }
    ],
    "relevance":0.5
},

"http://d.opencalais.com/genericHasher-1/802a1ebb-7fac-354f-b02f-6ef8442950d3":{
    "_typeGroup":"entities",
    "_type":"Organization",
    "name":"New York Jets",
    "organizationtype":"sports",
    "nationality":"American",
    "_typeReference":"http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/em/e/Organization",
    "instances":[
          {
          "detection":"[ Tebow caught a few training camp glimpses of the ]New York Jets[ during the summer of 2010 on HBO's Hard]",
          "prefix":" Tebow caught a few training camp glimpses of the ",
          "exact":"New York Jets",
          "suffix":" during the summer of 2010 on HBO's Hard",
          "offset":86,
          "length":13
          }
    ],
    "relevance":0.5
}
```

From this JSON, I would like to extract the "_type" and "name" only if the "typeGroup" == "entities".

For example, for the above JSON object the output should look like:

```
TVShow: Hard Knocks
Organization: New York Jets.
```

Could someone please help on how to do this in Python?

**[UPDATE 1]**

Based on the answer from Jatin I tried the following:

```
for key,value in json1.items():
    if value["_typeGroup"] == "entities":
        print value['_type'], value['name']
```

However, this results in the error KeyError: '_typeGroup'

I tried to see how the keys and value are printed as follows:

```
for key,value in json1.items():
    print key,value
```

This resulted in the following output (showing just one key, value pair):

```
http://d.opencalais.com/genericHasher-1/802a1ebb-7fac-354f-b02f-6ef8442950d3 {u'_typeReference': u'http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/em/e/Organization', u'_type': u'Organization', u'name': u'New York Jets', u'_typeGroup': u'entities', u'instances': [{u'suffix': u" during the summer of 2010 on HBO's Hard", u'prefix': u' Tebow caught a few training camp glimpses of the ', u'detection': u"[ Tebow caught a few training camp glimpses of the ]New York Jets[ during the summer of 2010 on HBO's Hard]", u'length': 13, u'offset': 86, u'exact': u'New York Jets'}], u'relevance': 0.5, u'nationality': u'American', u'organizationtype': u'sports'}
```

It appears to be a nested JSON. So i tried the following to access the inner Key Value pair as follows:

```
for key,value in json1.items():
    val1 = value
    for key,value in val1.items():
        if value["_typeGroup"] == "entities":
            print value['_type'], value['name']
```

However, it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: A json-object in Python is just another dictionary. Do you know how to access items of a dictionary?

Comment: I am a basic user of Python. I could access it by using  json1["http://d.opencalais.com/genericHasher-1/802a1ebb-7fac-354f-b02f-6ef8442950d3"]. However, I would like to do it by looping it through each key and check for conditions nested keys. Not sure how to do it.

Comment: I'm merely trying to improve your problem-tackling skills. So you know you want to use a *loop* to iterate over the *keys*. Python dictionaries provide *methods* to obtain all the keys, so that you don't have to type them manually. You could check out the documentation on `dict.keys()` or even more simply `for key in dict:`.

Comment: I have tried following Jatin's lead to solve it but still facing some issues. I have updated the OP. Please let me know where I am going wrong with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting that error because some of the values in your JSON don't have a `_typeGroup`. Try this:

```
for key,value in x.items():
    if value.get("_typeGroup", "") == "entities":
        print value['_type'], value['name']
```

Comment: This worked fine. Could you please explain what value.get("_typeGroup", "") actually does?

Comment: @Ravi it takes an element from the dictionary corresponding with the key `_typeGroup`, IF it exists, otherwise it will take the default value, which is given by the 2nd positional argument `""`, the empty string here. I do think jatin's answer lead you there, so you should consider upvoting his answer as well as he could not have known not all values were present.

Comment: Sure, the `get` method allows you to return a default value if the key you're looking for is not found in the dictionary ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)). I also just found out that it returns `None` if no default is specified, so the above could have just been `value.get("_typeGroup")`

Answer (score 2):

```
for key,value in json1.items():
    if value.get('typeGroup') == "entities":
        print value.get('_type'), value.get('name')
```

Try this and let me know. IT should work.

Comment: This throws an error: KeyError: '_typeGroup'. I have updated my original post with more information